# Unit testing a Grails custom taglib based on built-in Grails taglib

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I've an app based on Grails 1.3.7. And I need to write a unit test for a custom taglib that is based on the built-in taglib, `<g:select />` to be specific.

I checked out the solution on this [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176930/unit-testing-grails-tag) but the solution stated is not working in my case (some properties are not being prooperly mocked up).

The other solution that I found was [this](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/mastering-grails-taglibs). Using this approach, I get most of the properties of `FormTagLib` mocked up except for the `grailsApplication` property that `select` requires. The actual error that I get is `Cannot invoke method getArtefact() on null object`.

How can I properly write the unit test in such a case?

**Edit**
Here are my [test class](http://pastebin.com/icaALLfe) and the [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/cTrE6zTM). Line #45 on the stacktrace is the call to the `g.select` from my custom taglib. My custom taglib is something like

```
def clientSpecificQueues = {attrs->
    def queueList = taskService.getClientSpecificQueues(session.clientName)
    def queueLabel = "Some String"


    if (queueList.size() > 0){
        out << queueLabel
    else
        out << g.select(name:'queueId', from: queueList, optionKey: 'id', optionValue: 'name')



}
```

Comment: Can you post your test class and full stacktrace?

Comment: I've updated my question with the links to the stacktrace and the test class. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `grailsApplication` will never be mocked by default, it has too many responsibilities. I'd try to brutally patrially mock `grailsApplication` in `setUp()` by doing something like

```
tagLib.grailsApplication = [getArtefact: { -> return something suitable }]
```