# how to unit test grails' message tag

Tags: unit-testing, grails, message, taglib

in the controller there is an action:

```
    def delete = {
    withDomain {
        it.delete()
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'chocolateBar.label', default: 'ChocolateBar'), it.name])}"
        redirect action: 'list'
    }
}
```

which can be tested in development. while in **unit test**, the message(..) method throws exception ( groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: longtest.ChocolateBarController.message() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[code:chocolateBar.label, default:ChocolateBar]]):

```
    public void testDelete() {
    controller.params.id = '3'
    controller.delete()
    assert 'list'==controller.redirectArgs.action
}
```

After study, a **mockTagLib** method should be called during setup. But found no correct class name for built-in message(..). Please help.

Comment: found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176930/unit-testing-grails-tag?rq=1 answered, but the answer is not clear: tagLib is not a property of **ControllerTests.

Comment: I haven't done this in specific, but what happens when you do access controller.flashMessage after you have called the action?

Comment: Neither did I ever think of this problem. A controller with an action containing `message(..)` (which comes from a built-in Grails tag lib?) is under test, then the MissingMethodException was thrown.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem in unit controller test. like this:

```
//This is inside Spock test

@Shared
ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = null

@Shared
Closure mockMessage = {Map map ->
    return messageSource.getMessage((String)map.code, (Object[])map.args, Locale.default)
}

def setupSpec(){
    URL url = new File('grails-app/i18n').toURI().toURL()
    messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource()
    messageSource.bundleClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(url)
    messageSource.basename = 'messages'
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8")
}

def setup(){
    controller.metaClass.message = mockMessage
}
```

This code is for spock test, but main idea is also available for normal grails test.
In running phase(not test),
calling "message" in controller class results in calling "message" of ValidationTagLib class,
but they are not bind in unit test phase.
So I made almost same logic of "message" of ValidationTagLib,
and bind it(named "mockMessage") to controller.message.
With this code, you can execute "message" correctly in controller class in test.